# tns doctor says missing `ANDROID_HOME` even when it is set on circleCi

Tags: android, cloud, nativescript, circleci, circleci-2.0

I am trying to run a nativescript cloud build on circleci. I am using the docker image circleci/android:api-28-node8-alphawhich already has ANDROID_HOME set and is pointing to correct location which you can see from the output of the build [cloud build](https://circleci.com/gh/rakeshgirase/CloudBuild/50) and here is my [config.yml](https://github.com/rakeshgirase/CloudBuild/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml) file as I tried to check what it is set to and what are the files under that location. I am not sure why tns doctor still says ANDROID_HOME is missing .

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Rakesh

Comment: I had a look at the logs, it doesn't seem to complain about `ANDROID_HOME` but instead it claims appropriate api levels are not installed. Please double check on that, `android list target` might list the installed SDKs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the docker image to circleci/android:api-23-node8-alpha and it worked so the docker image required is the targed android sdk. Thanks to @Manoj.